# Adding line with specific df value to each bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My df is organized this way for example:

```
OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC | a | b  | c | d  | flagged | type | MedDRA_PT| **E** |
__________________________________________________________________________
UNITED STATES        |403|1243|473|4077|   yes   | disp |  Seizure |144.208|
__________________________________________________________________________
```

My data:

```
 structure(list(OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC = c("AUSTRALIA", "AUSTRIA", 
"BELGIUM", "BRAZIL", "CANADA"), a = c(4L, 7L, 20L, 5L, 11L), 
    b = c(31, 27, 100, 51, 125), c = c(872, 869, 856, 871, 865
    ), d = c(5289, 5293, 5220, 5269, 5195), w = c(876, 876, 876, 
    876, 876), x = c(5320, 5320, 5320, 5320, 5320), y = c(35L, 
    34L, 120L, 56L, 136L), z = c(6161, 6162, 6076, 6140, 6060
    ), N = c(6196, 6196, 6196, 6196, 6196), k = c("0.5", "0.5", 
    "0.5", "0.5", "0.5"), SOR = c(0.80199821407511, 1.52042360060514, 
    1.21312776329214, 0.615857869962066, 0.539569644832803), 
    log = c(-0.318329070860348, 0.604473324558599, 0.278731499148795, 
    -0.699330656240263, -0.890118907611227), LL99 = c(-0.695969674426877, 
    0.382102954188229, 0.198127619344382, -1.00534117464748, 
    -1.03425468471322), UL99 = c(-0.0544058884186467, 0.763880731966007, 
    0.337239065783058, -0.482651467660248, -0.785935460582379
    ), flagged = c("no", "no", "no", "no", "yes"), type = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "under"), MedDRA_PT = c("Seizure", "Seizure", 
    "Seizure", "Seizure", "Seizure"), E = c(5.11098506333901, 
    4.43283582089552, 16.3984674329502, 8.43063199848168, 20.8132820019249
    )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I am using ggplot2 to create a bar chart using the following piece of code:

```
test2 %>% #using test2 as the df
  ggplot(aes(a, OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("disp" = "#FF8C00",
                                "under" = "#7EC0EE",
                                "NA"="#EEE9E9"))+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(title = "Seizure",
       x = "Count",
       y = "")
```

What I would like to do is to add a black line in each bar correspondent to the **E** value, from the dataframe, for that country. However I haven't been successful. Can someone kindly guide me on how to  achieve this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand thank you very much for that! I have just added the code to a portion of my data, so people can reproduce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be via a `geom_segment`, where you map your `E` column on both the `x` and the `xend` position. "Tricky" part are the `y` positions. However, as a categorical axis is still a numeric axis we could add a helper column to your data which contains the numeric positions of your categorical `OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC` column. This helper column could then be mapped on the `y` and the `yend` aes needed by `geom_segment` where we also take into account the width of the bars:

```
library(ggplot2)

test2$OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC_num <- as.numeric(factor(test2$OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC))
width <- .9 # defautlt width of bars

ggplot(test2, aes(a, OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = E, xend = E, 
                   y = OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC_num - width / 2, 
                   yend = OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC_num + width / 2), 
               color = "black", size = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "disp" = "#FF8C00",
    "under" = "#7EC0EE",
    "NA" = "#EEE9E9"
  )) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(
    title = "Seizure",
    x = "Count",
    y = ""
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @stefan. Thank you, that was super helpful!
However, when I try to reorder the bar chart in an increasing order by the count value the  black lines don't follow the reorder. 

I have only changed the first line of the ggplot to include the reorder function as can be seen below: 
ggplot(test2, aes(a, OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC, fill = type, y=reorder(OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC,a))) +

All the rest of the code is the same. Do you know why aren't the black lines following the change of position and how can I solve it?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Hi. You probably did the reorder after the conversion to a numeric. Doing so the numerics are created from from the unordered version and the segements will be placed at the wrong position, i.e. reorder the categorical variable first, then apply the code to convert or create the numeric positions. If that does not fix the issue, then add your code as an edit to your post and I will have a look.

Comment: ... ah. Now i see that you added the code to your comment. And that's exactly what I guessed. Doing `test2$OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC <- reorder(test2$OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC, test2$a)` before `test2$OCCURED_COUNTRY_DESC_num <- ...` should fix the issue.